# C++: How do I create a collection field for storing a finite number of instances of a class?

Tags: c++, class, oop, vector, methods

I have a problem that requires I track tickets sold at a theatre. To do this I need to create a ShowTicket class. The class should contain a collection field for the rows, seat numbers, and whether the tickets have been sold or not. The class only needs to support 10 sold tickets. Assume a ticket that is not referenced before has a sold status of false.

Member functions must include:

`bool is_sold(string row, string seat);`

`void sell_seat(string row, string seat);`

`string print_ticket(string row, string seat);`

So I made the following class and methods:

```
class ShowTicket {
    string row;
    string seat_num;
    bool sold;
public:
    ShowTicket(string row = "-1",
               string seat_num = "-1",
               bool sold = false)
               :row(row),
               seat_num(seat_num),
               sold(sold){}
    bool is_sold(string new_row, string new_seat_num){return sold;}
    void sell_seat(string new_row, string new_seat_num){row = new_row; seat_num = new_seat_num; sold= true;}
    string print_ticket(string row, string seat_num) {
        string s;
        sold ? s = "sold" : s = "available";
        return row + " " + seat_num + " " + s;
    }
};
```

I need my main function to look like this:

```
int main() {
    ShowTicket myticket;

    if(!myticket.is_sold("AA","101"))
        myticket.sell_seat("AA","101");

    cout << myticket.print_ticket("AA","101") << endl;
    cout << myticket.print_ticket("AA","102") << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And return:

`AA 101 sold`

`AA 102 available`

*This is not required but it is possible to implement this without the 10 object limit. If you have time to include that version as well it would be much appreciated. Thanks to all.

Comment: If you need something that default constructs when it is referneced then a map is good.  If you `std::map<std::pair<std::string,std::string>,bool> tickets` then `tickets[std::make_pair("AA","102")]` will be false and `tickets[std::make_pair("AA","101")] = true;` will set it to true.  You don't need to use a pair -  a `struct ticket{ std::string row; std::string seat_num;}` would also work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The class you describe (with the misleading name `ShowTicket`) does not represent a single ticket; it represents the *state of the house,* the sold/unsold state of every ticket. So it must have a data structure that can hold that information, at least a container that can hold 10 tickets that have been sold.

Comment: OT, but if you really want to use the ternary conditional expressen, remember that it returns a result. So something like `std::string s = sold ? "sold" : "available"` would be better IMO.

Comment: And please don't put multiple statements on a single line, it makes the code much harder to read and understand.

Comment: Something like this: https://onlinegdb.com/r1xxDLd2D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to Jerry Jeremiah:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

class ShowTicket {
    using TicketsMap = std::map<std::pair<std::string,std::string>,bool>;
    static TicketsMap tickets; // needs to be defined outside the class
public:
    bool is_sold(std::string row, std::string seat_num){return tickets[{row,seat_num}];}
    void sell_seat(std::string row, std::string seat_num){tickets[{row,seat_num}]=true;}
    std::string print_ticket(std::string row, std::string seat_num) {
        return row + " " + seat_num + " " + (tickets[{row,seat_num}]?"sold":"available");
    }
};

ShowTicket::TicketsMap ShowTicket::tickets;

int main() {
    ShowTicket myticket;

    if(!myticket.is_sold("AA","101"))
        myticket.sell_seat("AA","101");

    std::cout << myticket.print_ticket("AA","101") << std::endl;
    std::cout << myticket.print_ticket("AA","102") << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When approaching a problem like this figuring out how many classes are needed and what they represent is one of the keys. Figuring out what the real world object types are can be helpful. So in a theater there are many objects; 1 Theater, potentially multiple viewing rooms, movies, tickets, concession stands, seats and many more. However, in this case you're dealing with three, one theater that's assumed to have only one movie playing in a single viewing room. You also have seats and tickets. But this problem really doesn't do anything with tickets. For instance you are not tracking who has it, who paid for it, what time it's sold. So you really only have two objects of interest a theatre and seats. So you'll need two classes to represent those two real world object. Now a seat doesn't have many theaters in it, but a theater does have many seats. So the theatre will need a collection of seats associated with it. In this case you'll you will also have a ShowTicket class, since that's a given constraint of the problem. Logically the ShowTicket is most closely related to the theatre, since you've been told it should contain a container of seats.

Now what attributes of a seat are interesting in this problem? Whether it reclines? It's price? Who's sitting in it? What row it's in? What's its number in that row? Has the ticket been sold? The answer to those questions. You'll have to decide where and how to store that information within the class. For instance is the seat position going to be represented as a string, like "A101" or is it going to be represented by a row 'A' and a seat 101. And are those values going to be strings, a single character or an integer.

And how are you going to represent sold verses available? Are you going to put available seats in one container class and sold seats in another containers object? Or are you simply going to store a bool in the class indicating sold or not?

There are many ways to code a solution to this problem that will work. And some will be more efficient than others. And some when written in production code, that may be modified over and over again for years will be easier to maintain due to a simple, clear design.

Obviously I'm not providing a concrete solution to your problem. Instead I'm trying to help to provide the thought processes to guide you to solving many programming problems.